# Why does Android use a separate partition, rather than a directory, for storing temporary data?

Tags: android, partition

As we know, `/cache` is a mount point to a separate partition for storing temporary data.

I think a directory is easy-to-manage and far more elastic than a partition.

Why does Android not use a directory under `/data`, say `/data/cache`, for that?

Is there any special considerations behind the design?

Comment: Why vote for closing this question?

Comment: because this kind of questions is considered off-topic by some users (I didn't vote for closing, though).

Comment: @xmllmx Wrong place to ask

Comment: @aga, for a programmer, I think, knowing why is even more important than just knowing how. So, I think this question is appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: Stack Overflow is about specific problems (like a stack Overflow). This is probably slightly more on topic on Programmers, and probably on topic on Android.

Comment: @xmllmx I know, and sometimes I make such questions or answer them myself. I only told why some people vote to close it. :)